# Stability of certain nuclei

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics

My question concerns this exercise that I was given:

In a simple model of the atomic nucleus, each nucleon (proton or neutron, each
with spin-$\frac{1}{2}$
) moves in the $d=3$ harmonic potential $V(\mathbf{X})=V_0 + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2\mathbf{X}^2$, interpreted as being
created by the other nuclei.

Suggest why the nuclear isotopes 4He, 16O and 40Ca
are especially stable. [Helium, oxygen and calcium nuclei contain 2, 8 and 20
protons, respectively. All protons are identical.]

Earlier in the question, we noted that the allowed energy eigenvalues are $V_0 + (N + \frac{3}{2})\hbar\omega, N\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ where the degeneracy of the Nth level is $\frac{1}{2}(N+1)(N+2)$, so this may be related.

I really don't know where to begin with this, but clearly its somehow down to the fact that the unifying characteristic is equal neutron and proton numbers... I'm especially perplexed as to how spin and parity comes into it, other than the fact that this spin value tells us that the nucleons are fermions which then tells us the obvious stuff about exchanging protons/neutrons.